# in awk, how to search for complex pattern combination after common tolower( ) operation

Tags: awk

I'm trying to select some paper titles from a long list using keywords.
Here is the sample line which is simplified for the purpose of this question.

```
tolower($0) ~ /model selection/ || tolower($0) ~ /structure learning/{print}
```

With this line, I want to print any line containing 'model selection' or 'structure learning'. But for every pattern I add in that command line, I have to put this `tolower($0) ~` expression. Otherwise, awk will not print lines containing `Model selection` or `Structure learning`.  Isn't there a way to apply the pattern `after` tolower($0) ~ function?

After posting this question, I realized what I really want to do is to use logical pattern operation with the output of the tolower($0), something like (if I want to print line with `pattern1 and (pattern2 or pattern3)`)

```
tolower($0) ~ /pattern1&(pattern2|pattern3)/{print}
```

without repeating tolower()..  and also I want to search for pattern with tolower(), like /RL/ in $0.
Of course I can do

```
/RL/ || (tolower($0) ~ /pattern1/ && tolower($0) ~ /pattern2|pattern3/) {print}
```

But I want to use tolower() only once.

Comment: `tolower($0) ~ /model selection|structure learning/` in this case

Comment: Ah, this seems to be the answer I was looking for.! make it an anser and I'll select it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk for IGNORECASE (not really necessary as you could use tolower($0) but included for reference) and switch statements:

```
{
    IGNORECASE=1
    switch($0) {
    case /model selection/:
    case /structure learning/: print
    }
}
```

From your comments and updated question and tha fact you're still asking, this might be what you're looking for:

```
{ lc = tolower($0) }
lc ~ /(regexp_a)|(regexp_b)/ || /RL/
```

or:

```
{ lc = tolower($0) }
lc ~ /regexp_a/ ||
lc ~ /regexp_b/ ||
/RL/
```

They're regexps btw, not patterns.

Comment: Hi, thank. but I have to search for many patterns and I want to put the pattern variations in each single line. and I also want sometimes search for upperchracters like {/model selection/ || /structure learning/} with ignore case and /RL/ with case sensitive. Can you do it in one line?

Comment: I think the answer I was looking for was tolower($0) ~ /pattern_a | patern_b/ || $0 ~ /RL/ {print}. as Ry- above mentioned.

Comment: You should really updated your question with more truly representative sample input, output, and code as there are many was to do what you originally asked for which is `to do something like
tolower($0) ~ /model selection/ | /structure learning/ {print}
without repeating tolower`

Comment: I updated my question. Can I do what I want in awk? I read the man page, and it seems it's impossible.

Comment: Yeah you updated it but it still doesn't say anything about also needing case-sensitive comparisons like you alluded to in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55756068/in-awk-how-to-search-for-complex-pattern-combination-after-common-tolower-op/55756425?noredirect=1#comment98188832_55756425). wrt `it seems impossible` - huh? You said in that same comment that `the answer I was looking for was ...` so why is it now impossible? Unless I'm missing something - yes, you can do it in awk.

Answer (score 0):

IGNORECASE setup is gnu awk feature

```
awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} {$0 ~ /pattern1&(pattern2|pattern3)/ {print}  }'
```